# how to get the SUM from any Start date and any End date. (file.txt) Python

Tags: python

Hello I have been stuck on this for weeks. if i have a list saved in file.dat file or text file which contains the following information below:

```
1-3-2014,job4,51081.5,10
10-10-2014,job3,1010.1,35
4-2-2015,job2,61824.7,35
2-4-2016,Job1,222.1,12
```

(separated by commas because they be under different headings as shown below, i have already written code which displays it as below in a function)

```
print (" Heading1      Heading 2    heading 3   heading 4 ")

         1-3-2014      job4         $51081.5     10
         10-10-2014    job3         $1010.1      35
         4-2-2015      job2         $61824.7     35
         2-4-2016      jon1         $222.1       12
```

what i want.
user to input a start date(start date in my file e.g.. 1 3 2014)

user to input a end date(end date also from the file e.g. 4 2 2015)

program to print the sum (e.g. total is $......(what ever the total of the start $$ to the end date is combined) it should add the $ of the start date and all dates in between all the way to the end date and print the final sum.

thanks

code below as requested which i have tried but get the time data does not match format '%d/%m/%Y' . ( also is it possible to do this within a function as i have heard it may be the right way to go about it.

from datetime import datetime

```
begin_date = datetime.strptime(input('Enter start date (dd mm yyyy): '), '%d %m %Y')
end_date = datetime.strptime(input('Enter end date (dd mm yyyy): '), '%d %m %Y')

with open ('data.txt', 'r') as f:
total = 0
for line in f:
    strlist = line.rstrip().split(',')

    dt = datetime.strptime(strlist[0], '%d-%m-%Y')

    if begin_date <= dt <= end_date:
        total+=float(strlist[2].split('$')[1])




print(total)
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Show and we can help you to fix any errors.

Comment: yes but i get the error time data does not match format '%d/%m/%Y'. please see above in original post as i have included it

Comment: I have updated the post

Comment: Is the date you type in the format `%d/%m/%Y`, for example `02/06/2016`?

Comment: yes it is typed in that format

Comment: OK, but the data from your input file uses a different format `%d-%m-%Y`.

Comment: i try inputing it that way and it still gives me the errors.i have pretty much given up. all i want it to do is add the $ from the start and end date.

Comment: As Lutz said, your example data is in the format `%d-`%m-%Y`, plus in the first line of your loop you split the line on a dot, when in your example the columns are separated by commas.

Comment: okay so i corrected that.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can use following code,

```
from datetime import datetime

def calculate(file_name, s_date, e_date):
    dollar = 0
    _format = '%d-%m-%Y'
    start_date = datetime.strptime(s_date, _format)
    end_date = datetime.strptime(e_date, _format)
    with open(file_name) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            l = line.split(',')
            date = datetime.strptime(l[0], _format)
            if date >= start_date and date <= end_date:
                dollar = dollar + float(l[2])
    return dollar

start_date = raw_input('Enter start date')
end_date = raw_input('Enter end date')
result = calculate('file.dat', start_date, end_date)
print result
```

Comment: i just have to add the input (enter start date.. and also for the end date. i guess that goes on the same line as the start_date and also end_date?

Comment: Yeah, you can use input(prompt) or input_raw(prompt) function to get input from the user and pass them to this function

Comment: i added input functions on these lines  start_date = datetime.strptime(s_date, _format)(input('Enter start date(dd mm yyyy): ')
    end_date = datetime.strptime(e_date, _format)(input('Enter end date (dd mm yyyy): ') good?  by the way I'm getting an invalid syntax error on  end_date

Comment: i enter the dates like 1-3-2014 and 10-10-2014 and get the error 
ValueError: time data '\n' does not match format '%d-%m-%Y' ) what am i doing wrong